# Asp.Net MVC 5 DataAnnotations EmailAddressAttribute System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, out-of-memory, data-annotations

I have a strange problem. My application work good in dev environement. When I deploy in my remote server (with WebDeploy) the application start but when I fill the first form, I have this error :

> 2014-12-17 11:03:06,090 [13] FATAL - System.OutOfMemoryException: Une
>   exception de type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' a été levée.    à
>   Go16(RegexRunner )    à
>   System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexRunner.Scan(Regex regex, String
>   text, Int32 textbeg, Int32 textend, Int32 textstart, Int32 prevlen,
>   Boolean quick, TimeSpan timeout)    à
>   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Run(Boolean quick, Int32 prevlen,
>   String input, Int32 beginning, Int32 length, Int32 startat)    à
>   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(String input)    à
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute.IsValid(Object
>   value)    à
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object
>   value, ValidationContext validationContext)    à
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object
>   value, ValidationContext validationContext)    à
>   System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate(Object
>   container)    à
>   System.Web.Mvc.ModelValidator.CompositeModelValidator.d__1.MoveNext()
>   à System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)    à
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)    à
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)    à
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)    à
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)

It's seems that it is during the model validation, my model is :

```
public class UserCredentialsViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ValidationMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailRequired", ErrorMessage = null)]
    [Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Labels))]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ValidationMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidEmailFormat", ErrorMessage = null)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ValidationMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordRequired", ErrorMessage = null)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Labels))]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT :**

I restart my website in IIS and there is no error but I have a new error :

> 2014-12-17 11:27:34,163 [15] FATAL - System.Web.HttpCompileException
>   (0x80004005): Un composant externe a levé une exception.    à
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()    à
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()    à
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)    à
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)    à
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)    à
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound)    à
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)    à
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer)    à
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   à
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    à
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    à
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)    à
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)

After having refreshed several times, the error disappeard... I don't really understand...

Comment: Long shot, but is your server actually low on free memory?

Comment: it's can be a good suggestion, effectively the server contains only 2GB of memory and is using currently 1.66GB. Thanks !